# runtime polymorphic invocation of pure virtual function via std::reference_wrapper behaving inconsistently

Tags: c++, c++11, std, reference-wrapper, run-time-polymorphism

I present to you this code riddle:

Using this compiler:

> user@bruh:~/test$ g++ --version
>
> g++ (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
>   Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

...and this compile string:

> g++ main.cpp class.cpp -o main -g

...and these files:

class.hpp:

```
class base {

  public:

    base();

    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class derived : public base {

  public:

    derived( unsigned int id );

    void f() override;

    unsigned int id; 
};
```

class.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "class.hpp"

base::base() {

  return;
}

derived::derived( unsigned int id )
  :
  id( id ),
  base() {

  return;
}

void derived::f() {

  std::cout << "Ahoy, Captain! I am " << id << std::endl;

  return;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

#include "class.hpp"

int main() {

  unsigned int n_elements;

  std::cout << "enter the number of elements: ";

  std::cin >> n_elements;

  std::cout << std::endl;

  std::vector< class derived > v;

  std::vector< std::reference_wrapper< class base > > base_vector_0;

  std::vector< std::reference_wrapper< class base > > base_vector_1;

  for( unsigned int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++ ) {

    v.emplace_back( i );

    base_vector_0.emplace_back( v[ i ] );
  }

  for( unsigned int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++ ) {

    base_vector_1.emplace_back( v[ i ] );
  }

  std::cout << "sanity check:" << std::endl;

  for( unsigned int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++ ) {

    class base &base = v[ i ];

    base.f();
  }

  std::cout << "case 1:" << std::endl;

  for( unsigned int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++ ) {

    base_vector_1[ i ].get().f();
  }

  std::cout << "case 0:" << std::endl;

  for( unsigned int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++ ) {

    base_vector_0[ i ].get().f();
  }

  return 0;
}
```

...I get the following output:

```
user@bruh:~/test$ ./main
enter the number of elements: 1

sanity check:
Ahoy, Captain! I am 0
case 1:
Ahoy, Captain! I am 0
case 0:
Ahoy, Captain! I am 0
harrynh3@bruh:~/test$ ./main
enter the number of elements: 2

sanity check:
Ahoy, Captain! I am 0
Ahoy, Captain! I am 1
case 1:
Ahoy, Captain! I am 0
Ahoy, Captain! I am 1
case 0:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My questions:

1. Why does this **not segfault** when the user supplied argument = 1?
2. Why does this **segfault** when the user supplied argument > 1?

My short explanation of what the code does:

Creates many objects derived from an abstract base class. Stores references to the objects in containers as std::reference_wrapper around abstract base class reference. Creates the containers of std::reference_wrapper slightly differently. Calls the derived override of pure virtual function via the std::reference_wrappers. Segfaults specifically in the case denoted in the source code above.

I implore the C++ experts... Please help me! This is fascinating and I have no idea why it is happening! I've probably done something dumb.

Answer (score 1):

You create dangling reference in this snippet of code:

```
  for( unsigned int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++ ) {

    v.emplace_back( i ); // [1]

    base_vector_0.emplace_back( v[ i ] ); // [2]
  }
```

[1] add new item, [2] store reference to this item. If vector was rebuit while calling `emplace_back`, all references are invalidated and you refer to item which doesn't exist.
 `vector` is rebuilt when its  current capacity is exceed by adding new items into it.

If you want to store exactly `n_elements` in `v` vector and avoid rebuilding vector you can call `reserve`:

```
  std::vector< class derived > v;
  v.reserve(n_elements); // added

  std::vector< std::reference_wrapper< class base > > base_vector_0;

  std::vector< std::reference_wrapper< class base > > base_vector_1;

  for( unsigned int i = 0; i < n_elements; i++ ) {

    v.emplace_back( i );

    base_vector_0.emplace_back( v[ i ] );
  }
```

now, when `emplace_back` is called no references are invalidated, and accessing these references by `base_vector_0` is safe.

Comment: From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back: If the new size() is greater than capacity() then all iterators and references (including the past-the-end iterator) are invalidated. Otherwise only the past-the-end iterator is invalidated. <-- I overlooked that very important clause. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your code does this: it stores a reference to temporary in the vector (encapsulated in a `reference_wrapper`); that reference immediately becomes dangling, as soon as control exits loop body, right after pushing it; next, you retrieve this dangling reference and invoke a virtual member function on it, thus forcing your program to behave undefinedly; and once you ignite an UB it's like a singularity point where all the rational explanations stop.

BTW, control will eventually exit a function once reaching its body end even if you don't put `return` in there. 0_o